# count comma-separated values from a column - sql

Tags: mysql

I want count the length of a comma separated column
I have use these

```
(LENGTH(Col2) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Col2,",","")) + 1)
```

in my select query.

**Demo:**

```
id | mycolumn
1    2,5,8,60
2    4,5,1
3    5,Null,Null
```

query result for first two row is coming correctly.for 1 = 4 ,2 = 3 but for 3rd row it is calculating null value also.

Comment: What is the type of `mycolumn` ?

Comment: column type : varchar

Comment: My guess is that your actual third record is `NULL` and not what you have listed.  Can you verify this by a query?

Comment: user has selected only one subcategory thatswhy null is getting stored in the database

Comment: Does the contents of _mycolumn_ refer to another table? For example are they the ids? If so this is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I believe the actual state of your data is:

```
id | mycolumn
1    2,5,8,60
2    4,5,1
3    NULL
```

In other words, the entire value for `mycolumn` in your third record is `NULL`, likely from doing an operation involving a `NULL` value.  If you actually had the text `NULL` your current query should still work.

The way to get around this would be to use `COALESCE(val, "")` when handling the `NULL` values in your strings.

Comment: user can select only one value also

Comment: there are total 6 options to select.user can select option as per his skills.it can be only one or all the options.so the values are gettting stored as 5,null,null

Answer (score 0):

Crude way of doing it is to replace the occurances of ',Null' with nothing first:-

```
SELECT a.id, (LENGTH(REPLACE(mycolumn, ',Null', '')) - LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(mycolumn, ',Null', ''),",","")) + 1)
FROM some_table a
```

If the values refer to the id of rows in another table then you can join against that table using FIND_IN_SET and then count the matches (assuming that the string 'Null' is not an id on that other table)

```
SELECT a.id, COUNT(b.id)
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN id_list_table b
ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.mycolumn)
GROUP BY a.id
```